# В(а/о)лтузить - орфография и этимология

Tags: орфография, этимология

Авторитетные словари последовательно дают написание через А.
Викисловарь - оба варианта.
В сети с большим отрывом лидирует написание через О.

Два последних факта не дают просто отмахнуться от неправильного варианта. 
Есть ли какое-то основание для написания через О? Может, объяснение лежит в плоскости этимологии?

Comment: Не скажу уверенно насчёт связи, но в украинском есть слово "вовтузити" [вовтузыты] (обычно в форме "вовтузитися"), но с другим значением: 1) возиться, метушиться; 2) заниматься нудной кропотливой работой.

Comment: grizzly OK, спасибо. Слово это знаю, но сам бы не вспомнил. Надо подумать... А этимологию можете дать?

Comment: Ха! Для **"вовтуження"** один из переводов **"валанданье"**. То есть переход А <> О тут вообще скорее всего закономерен. Осталось разобраться со значением, тогда можно будет считать, что волтузиться - украинизм.  Ну или наоборот, исконная форма, не подвергшаяся воздействию аканья.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл в одном из этимологических словарей подтверждение Вашей догадки:

> [вовтузити] «шарпати, сіпати, бити», вовтузитися «возитися»; — р.
>   [валтузить] «бити, шарпати», [волтузить] «тс», [валтожиться,
>   волтозиться, валтажиться] «возитися, доглядати», [валторить] «бити»; —
>   дериват якогось давнього східнослов'янського дієслова; невдала спроба
>   (Фасмер І 270) зведення  р. [валтажиться] до фр. avantager «сприяти»,
>   а р. [валторить] — до р.   валить і [торить] «штовхати».

Приведу перевод некоторых слов:
бити — бить;
возитися — возиться;
доглядати — присматривать;
якогось давнього східнослов'янського дієслова — какого-то древнего восточнославянского глагола;
невдала спроба зведення  — неудачная попытка сведения;
сприяти — способствовать;
штовхати — толкать.

Остальное, думаю, понятно по контексту.

Comment: *невдала спроба зведення — неудачная попытка сведения* - неудач**на** попытка сведения - здесь предикатив в русском должен быть. Попытка - какова?. .